# MVC4 Dynamically created ActionLink working unexpectedly

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using MVC4 and Razor

I am getting unexpected results when I dynamically create a ActionLink and hoping somebody could explain why: The problem is that when I pass null as a htmlAttribute, the URL is generated correctly. However, when I pass in a value, the Area section of the URL are messed up.

```
<li> @Html.ActionLink(link.LinkText, link.ActionName, link.ControllerName, rvd,link.ActionName.Equals(currentAction) && link.ControllerName.Equals(currentController)? new { @class = "currentMenuItem" }:null)</li>

http://localhost:48000/Accounts/Forum/TopicsGrid?Count=2&Keys=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BKeyCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D&Values=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BValueCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D
```

When I pass null as the htmlAttribute its CORRECT:

```
<li> @Html.ActionLink(link.LinkText, link.ActionName, link.ControllerName, rvd, null)</li>   

http://localhost:48000/Forums/Forum/TopicsGrid/1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActionLink()` [does not have](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink.aspx) a `Dictionary, Object` overload.
Since your last parameter is an `Object`, the routeValues parameter is interpreted as an objetc as well, so it reads the properties of the `RouteValudDictionary` class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - not sure if I understand. I am passing a value to the htmlAttribute parameter. The "rvd" parameter is the RouteValueDictionary parameter.

Comment: @Greg: Yes.  But it's treating that as an object.

Comment: if I explicitly pass the new { @class = "currentMenuItem" } as the htmlAttribute it works, but obviously that is going to highlight ALL the links. So why when I use the "link.ActionName.Equals(currentAction) ..." does it fail?

Comment: @Greg: Pass a dictionary instead of an object.

Comment: I tried this and it still doesnt work: var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        myDictionary.Add("class", "currentMenuItem"); <li> @Html.ActionLink(link.LinkText, link.ActionName, link.ControllerName, rvd, myDictionary)</li>

Comment: That should be a `Dictionary<Strinhg, Object>`, to match the overload.

Comment: Ok - Im getting somewhere now. The URL's are looking correct. Last Question: How do I pass the "@class" , "currentMenuItem" to the Dictionary<string,object>() ?

Comment: `new Dictionary<string,object>() { { "class", "currentMenuItem" }, ... }`